# how to access the value of variable outside its scope in snapshot.foreach

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

return statment return null value outside the foreach of the variable, I know the foreach loop creates its own scope , i need to return the value , how can i do that .....

```
this.selectedUserMessages = this.changeUserList.switchMap(Userid => {
   if (Userid) {

    var self = this;
    this.loadingSerivice.isLoading.next(true);
    var ref = db.database.ref(`wfffsdf/usesdfdsfsrs/${Userid}/ress`);
    var i = 0;
    ref.once("value")
     .then(function(snapshot) {

      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       var key = childSnapshot.key;
       // childData will be the actual contents of the child
       var invitedList = childSnapshot.val();
       self.invList.push({
        invitedid: invitedList
       });
       var invitedlistid = self.invList[i]['invitedid']['invitedBy'];
       //console.log(invitedlistid);
       if (invitedlistid == "asfsafafasfsafsafs") {
        //console.log("thread"+threadKey);
        self.ChatKey = key;
        //console.log(self.ChatKey+""+ db.database.ref(`1dfgsdfgdfhfdh/tdfsdfhsfhfhfdh/${key}/messages`)); 
       }
       i++;
      });
      self.chatMessages = self.getMessages(self.ChatKey);
      //  console.log(self.chatMessages);
     });
    return this.chatMessages;
   }
   return of(null);
  }
```

return this.chatMessages give null value...

Comment: In Javascript, `var` has function-level scope.  `ForEach` creates it's own scope because you are passing a function to it.  However, that's the scope of the inner variables.  The outer variables are captured and work fine inside of the ForEach.  Scope is not your problem.  Your problem is that you are using a Promise to handle the database query and then attempting to immediately return the stream.  You are mixing Observables and Promises.  Everything inside `then` is executed after `return this.chatMessages`.  Give me a minute to find you an example of using Rx.

Comment: thanks for your reply @JamesPoag , i am new to angular and firebase

Comment: Ok, this is [RxFire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxfire).  It's a relatively new package from the Firebase team for using RxJS Observables.  Since you are using the Realtime Database, you will want to [look at these examples](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/rxfire/docs/database.md#list-observables).  List() will emit a stream of child changes. You can `pipe()` this stream through a `map()` operator to do additional processing (or extract the `val()` and include the `key` as in the example).  what you do in `map()` is similar to what you do in ForEach.

Comment: [Here is a video](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/introduction-to-rxfire-rxjs-for-firebase/) that demonstrates using RxFire.  They use FireStore instead of Realtime database, but there are other videos on that site related to Rx observables.

Comment: Thanks , will look into it

Comment: Hey James. Thanks for helping a fellow developer here. Given the amount of information you provided, would you mind writing it up into an answer?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the scope of the variables aren't the problem.  In Javascript, `var` is scoped to surrounding function.  In the example code provided, `forEach` is being passed a `function`, so all of its variables are scoped as declared.  Outer variables are captured in the inner function so they behave properly as well.

The problem is that the inner `promise` is not resolving before the `switchmap` returns a value.

---

To understand fully what's going on, let's take a look at what the code is currently doing and what it should be doing instead.

For the sake of argument, I'm going to assume the following definitions (even though I know they are not correct):

```
selectedUserMessages : Observable<[]>;
      changeUserList : Observable<String>;
```

Here, `changeUserList` is a stream of string events that represents the current selected `UserId`.  `selectedUserMessages` will be an array of messages associated with the currently selected user.

The code above is simplified to the following meaning:

```
this.selectedUserMessages =
  // when changeUserList changes, switch selectedUserMessages to this new stream
  this.changeUserList.switchMap(Userid => {
    if (Userid) {

      // grab DB reference to user child list
      var ref = db.database.ref(`wfffsdf/usesdfdsfsrs/${Userid}/ress`);

      // CREATE A PROMISE TO QUERY THE DATABASE
      ref.once("value") // query once
        .then(function (snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var key = childSnapshot.key;
            var val = childSnapshot.val();

            // process child
          });

          // store result
          this.chatMessages = this.getMessages(this.ChatKey);

        }); // END OF PROMISE

      // RETURN IMMEDIATELY, BEFORE PROMISE RESOLVES
      return this.chatMessages;
    }
    return of(null); // return null stream
  }
```

The issue being that the switchmap call returns `this.chatMessages` before the inner promise resolves.

---

`switchmap` has an interesting feature: you *can* return a promise from inside switchmap and it will wait on the promise.  This is one way to [mix Promises and Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875).

Returning a promise from inside the switchmap looks like:

```
this.selectedUserMessages =
  // when changeUserList changes, switch selectedUserMessages to this new stream
  this.changeUserList.switchMap(Userid => {
    if (Userid) {

      // grab DB reference to user child list
      let ref = db.database.ref(`wfffsdf/usesdfdsfsrs/${Userid}/ress`);

      // !!!! RETURN A PROMISE TO QUERY THE DATABASE !!!!
      return ref.once("value") // query once
        .then(function (snapshot) {

          let results = [];
          snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            let key = childSnapshot.key;
            let val = childSnapshot.val();
            // process child //
            results.push(/*processing results*/);
          });

          return results;

        }); // END OF PROMISE
    }
    else
      return of(null); // return null stream
  }
```

---

With that being said, there's an alternative to mixing Promises and Observables for Firebase called [RxFire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxfire). It's a relatively new package from the Firebase team for using RxJS Observables. Since you are using the Realtime Database, you will want to [look at these examples](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/rxfire/docs/database.md#list-observables). List() will emit a stream of child changes. You can `pipe()` this stream through a `map()` operator to do additional processing (or extract the val() and include the key as in the example). what you do in map() is similar to what you do in `forEach`.

[AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/introduction-to-rxfire-rxjs-for-firebase/) has an example using RxFire on FireStore.

Comment: thanks for your reply @james , can you show me how rxFire will work with real time db , and the above answer return results; gets undefined outside foreach

Comment: Also if i write return result inside the promise , it doesnot subscribe to change ,

Comment: this.chatroom.selectedUserMessages.subscribe(userChatMessages =>{
                              if(userChatMessages){
                                   // console.log("Hello");
                                    this.userChatMessages = userChatMessages;
                                   // console.log("saasasf"+userChatMessages);
                                    this.loadingService.isLoading.next(false);  
                                }
                              })
          );

Comment: Can you put a debug break at `foreEach` and step through to make sure that `results` are being correctly produced?

Comment: Also, switch to arrow functions... `snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {` should be `snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {`

Comment: it solved can you help me with duplication of messages returning from firebase